# Programmatically populate a multi-select field in SharePoint Online via the m365 spo tool

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to create a list item with a multiselect field, according to the `m365 spo` [documentation](https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/cmd/spo/listitem/listitem-add/). It feels like I have tried all possible variations, but I cannot get it to work at all.

Is there any official guide as to the syntax for a multi-select value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for whomever bangs their heads against this in the future, the format for the seeds of a multi-lookup field is the following:

```
Id;Value;#
```

Where `;#` is the separator. You may use `#` as a wildcard for a value, ending up with the following example where I am adding the related entities with `Id` 3 and 5 to the seed:

```
3;#;#5;#
```

or one single entity:

```
1;#
```

or three entities:

```
2;#;#3;#;#5;#
```

There seems to be a tiny bit of tolerance on the trailing value, but I did not experiment much with this.

PS: it works, and I am very happy, but dear reader know this: if you feel the need for some eye-bleach after reading this, you are not alone!